# Add multiple co-authors while creating node

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, users

I have a content type proposal. Now I would like to have multiple co-authors of the node. I want to give the author the opportunity to add users like this:

[image]

The users have to be entity references. I know there is a module [Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) but how can I have a collection of entity references that bundles the "co-authors". The module doesn't work with Field Collection module.

Has anyone encountered this and is there a module for this or a simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at these two modules

https://www.drupal.org/project/references
https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference

They're both quite similar.

They allow you to add user reference fields to your content type. On the field you created, set the number of values to be unlimited and then the author can select as many co authors as they want.

Comment: If you need special access on top of what those modules offer, you can write your own permissions in a custom module and have your access callback check field values.